# Spark SQL - How to set variable of a sql query in pyspark and use that for further sql queries?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Important note -
we have to use set as have to read RDS views and not RDS tables. So need answers according to that

Need to find Spark SQL queries that allows to declare set variable in the query and then that set variable can be used further in SQL query.

For example this two sql statement working in RDS DB directly but not when doing it in PYSPARK

```
set @id = 'test123';
SELECT * FROM db.rds_view;
```

```
spark.sql("SET id='test123'")
spark.sql("select * from db.rds_view where id = ${id};")
```

Error showing

```
java.sql.SQLException: @id is null
```

Comment: you can just assign `id = 'test123'` and use [string formatters](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp)

Comment: we have to use set as have to read RDS views and not RDS tables. Can you tell how to read RDS views with it?

Comment: you won't need a `set` in pyspark. it's simply a variable that can be used with views as well as tables

Comment: in our rds view we are using GET_ID() so we have to set value first

Comment: how are you using the sql query? do you pass it in `spark.sql()`, then you no longer need to worry about `set`. anything else? add the details in the question.

Comment: as mentioned above using `spark.sql()`. if not using `SET` error coming - `java.sql.SQLException: @id is null value`

Comment: that's odd -- i'm not able to replicate your issue

Answer (score 0):

```
d1= [('abc', 1, 3),('test123', 3, 9),]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(d1, ['id','n1', 'n2'])
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("rds_view")

spark.sql("select * from rds_view ").show(3)
# +-------+---+---+
# |     id| n1| n2|
# +-------+---+---+
# |    abc|  1|  3|
# |test123|  3|  9|
# +-------+---+---+

id = 'test123'
spark.sql(f"select * from rds_view where id = '{id}' ").show(3)
# +-------+---+---+
# |     id| n1| n2|
# +-------+---+---+
# |test123|  3|  9|
# +-------+---+---+
```

Comment: we have to use set as have to read RDS views and not RDS tables. Can you tell how to read RDS views with it?

Comment: try this `id = 'test123'
spark.sql(f"select * from rds_view where id = '{id}' ").show(3)` .  And replace `rds_view` with ur real RDS View

Comment: same error showing - java.sql.SQLException: @id is null